# Weird behavior Instance bullet prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If the player not move and just stand the prefab bullet is normal movement (Picture A).
My prefab showed bad behavior while the player is running or moving (Picture B).

[image: Please Check the Picture]

This is my firePos script:

```
public class FirePos : MonoBehaviour {
    public bool _facingRight;
    public GameObject bulletRight, bulletLeft;
    bool canShootFire;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        canShootFire = true;
        _facingRight = GameObject.Find ("Player").GetComponent<PlayerManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K) && canShootFire && GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerManager>().facingRight){
            canShootFire = false;
            Instantiate (bulletRight, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            StartCoroutine ("Firing");
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.K) && canShootFire && !GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerManager>().facingRight){
            canShootFire = false;
            Instantiate (bulletLeft, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            StartCoroutine ("Firing");
        }

    }

    IEnumerator Firing(){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (.5f);
        canShootFire = true;
    }

}
```

This for bullet movement

```
public class bulletRight : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    transform.Translate (Vector2.right*speed*Time.deltaTime,0);
    Destroy (gameObject,1.5f);
}
}
```

Comment: you should send bullet script. How is bullet move ?

Comment: is this script attached to your Player object?

Comment: @MustafaErdemKöşk oke I just do it.

Comment: @Hristo yes FirePos Script is child of The Player

Comment: When you instantiate the bullet does it become a child of the Player? or does it have no parent `GameObject`?

Comment: In the inspector the bullet became (Clone) and it is Independent game Object.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just physics. You assume the initial speed of your bullet is zero, but it's not. It's the current speed of the shooter. Try setting that initial speed in the bullet object and adding it to `speed`.

Comment: Sorry I'am too beginner to understand that your suggest. Will be appreciate if you write the code to be. Thanks